# TQDM nested progress bar printing new bars every iteration

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

Hello fellow developers,

I am trying to implement a nested TQDM progress bar where the description updates every iteration. According to the TQDM documents, it was supposed to be 2 bars. Lets say the outer bar and then the inner bar. So as the inner bar reached 100% it fills up the outer bar progress a certain percentage and then goes again into the inner bar. However in my code, it is printing a complete new bar line ever iteration whether its the inner loop or the outer loop (refer to the image)

[image: Console Output]

Can any one please point me out where is the mistake i am doing?

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
def start_loop1():
    with tqdm(total=10, desc = "Outer Loop", position=0, leave=True) as pbar1:
        for i in range(10):
            print ("working on outer iteration - {}".format(i))
            pbar1.set_description("Outer Loop Iteration - {}".format(i))
            pbar1.refresh()
            time.sleep(2)
            start_loop2()
            pbar1.update(1)
            
def start_loop2():
    with tqdm(total=5, desc = "Inner Loop", position=1, leave=True) as pbar2:
        for i in range(5):
            print ("working on inner iteration - {}".format(i))
            pbar2.set_description("Inner Loop Iteration - {}".format(i))
            pbar2.refresh()
            time.sleep(5)
            pbar2.update(1)
        pbar2.reset()
            
#%% Standalone Run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_loop1()
```